# Can you change the Minecraft mob Despawn Radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a bunch of Mob spawners in my survival game, but every time I go from one end to the other the mobs keep despawning, I was wondering if it was possible to change the despawn radius from 128 to something higher.

I am looking for specifically a game command, or code edit, or even a small mod.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I did, I spent a while searching online and found no real solution to my specific question. I've been out of the minecraft loop for a little while (stopped before 1.9, ironically) and have been recently playing it a couple times a week. I manually mined and built like 50 block high spawners, and they work really well, but only work when I am literally under them/ very near them. the size of my "above-ground"  working area is just a little too large for all the spawners to stay spawning.

Comment: I'd suggest adding that to your question.  Currently, we have no indication that you've done anything at all, which we don't respond well to.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, outside of larger server/plugin ecosystems like Sponge, which includes a [global config file that allows this](https://docs.spongepowered.org/stable/en/server/getting-started/configuration/sponge-conf.html). There is no small single player solution to this problem. The only real solution would be to clear one mob system before moving 128 blocks away to another one, or simply live with the despawns.

Comment: Thanks, Disappointing there is no single player command for it. 
Really strange how a question can be downvoted.

Comment: ... or set `PersistanceRequired` on all your entities and implement despawning manually with command blocks.